# Сheck for a non-existent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some code that updates `div` and adds +1 value

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
  });

  $('.like-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var targetElement=$(this);
    $(this).addClass('active');

    let href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
      url: href,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function() {
        var current = parseInt(targetElement.find('.comments-sub-header__item-icon-count').html());
          targetElement.find('.comments-sub-header__item-icon-count').html(current+1)
     },
    });
  });
});
```

On click, I add the class `active`, `$(this).addClass('active');` and an action occurs which in `succes`, when I click again, this action is triggered again, so I need to check that such an action should be done only when the `active` class does not exist

I try to check this way

```
success: function() {
        if (targetElement.hasClass('active')) { 
          return false;
        }

        else {
          var current= parseInt(targetElement.find('.comments-sub-header__item-icon-count').html());
          targetElement.find('.comments-sub-header__item-icon-count').html(current+1)
        }
     },
```

But this does not work, there are no errors, just the value +1 is not added

This is how, in principle, the system for adding likes works for me

```
Route::post('article/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@postLike');
```

```
public function postLike($id, Request $request) {
        $article = Article::find($id);

        if(!$article){
            return abort(404);
        }

        $type = $request->input('type');
      
        if ($article->hasLikedToday($type)) {
            return response()
                ->json([
                    'message' => 'You have already liked the Article '.$article->id.' with '.$type.'.',
                ]);
        }
    
        $cookie = $article->setLikeCookie($type);
      
        $article->increment("like_{$type}");
    
        return response()
            ->json([
                'message' => 'Liked the Article '.$article->id.' with '.$type.'.',
                'cookie_json' => $cookie->getValue(),
            ])
            ->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```

```
public function hasLikedToday(string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        if (!array_key_exists($this->id, $articleLikes)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($type, $articleLikes[$this->id])) {
            return false;
        }

        $likeDatetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $articleLikes[$this->id][$type]);

        return ! $likeDatetime->addDay()->lt(now());
    }

    public function setLikeCookie(string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = Cookie::get('article_likes', '[]');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        $articleLikes[$this->id][$type] = now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $articleLikesJson = json_encode($articleLikes);

        return cookie()->forever('article_likes', $articleLikesJson);
    }
```

```
<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}?type=heart" class="comments-sub-header__item like-button {{ $article->hasLikedToday('heart') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon">
        <div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon-count">
            {{ $article->like_heart }}
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}?type=finger" class="comments-sub-header__item like-button {{ $article->hasLikedToday('finger') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon">
        <div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon-count">
            {{ $article->like_finger }}
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

When you click on the `like-button`, this code

```
var current = parseInt(targetElement.find('.comments-sub-header__item-icon-count').html());
targetElement.find('.comments-sub-header__item-icon-count').html(current+1)
```

adds +1 to the value and updates the div in which this number is +1, but now it turns out that if we click again, we get another +1, and so on. I need to make sure that +1 is added only on the first click, for this I try to use the active class, and make a check that if it is active, then we no longer add

Comment: Your `hasClass()` will always be true since you always call `addClass()` before that. Note that it's not entirely clear what the expected behavior is here. Why is there no data sent in the POST? A more detailed explanation of how you expect this to work would help

Comment: @charlietfl I added to the post how everything works for me and how the POST should work

Comment: Well actually you just added  a bunch of code that doesn't help clarify what the specific problem is. A written explanation is what I was referring to

Comment: @charlietfl Added some more explanations at the end of the post

Comment: Just check before you add the class and don't do anything ( ajax or counter)  if the class already exists. Also assumes that you add the class server side when applicable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of your problems is that you add the "active" class always, not only if success is achieved.

Also, you have the anchor around all the divs. That could cause that clicking on the div could make the `this` be the div and not the anchor.

`if (targetElement.hasClass('active')) {`

This part if correct. The problem is you need to be sure if the anchor is always the targe element independently of where you click.

Here is a working example:

HTML

```
 <a href="#" class="like-button">Like
  <div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon">
    <div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon-count">0</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

  $('.like-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var targetElement = $(this);

   
    if (targetElement.hasClass('active')) {
        console.log("is active");
      return false;
    } else {
        console.log("is not active");
      var counter = targetElement.find('.comments-sub-header__item-icon-count');
      var current = parseInt(counter.html());
      console.log(current);
      
      counter .html(current + 1)
      
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
});
```

I created a jsfiddle so you can play around with it.

https://jsfiddle.net/shizus/wqa4782z/1/